# Best way to add incremental numbers to a column in a .csv file

Tags: r, csv, tableau-api

I have a dataset (in the form of a .csv file) which includes a number of columns, one of which includes "genres" (of TV programmes). There are multiple columns (one for title of programme, one for episode number, one for synopsis, etc.) I want to create a new column that consecutively numbers each entry for "genre". E.g. So the first instance of documentary should be followed by "1", the second entry followed by "2", and so on. Then, when there is a new genre, it should start over from "1". If that's not clear, this is what I mean:

```
Documentary, 1
Documentary, 2 
Documentary, 3
Documentary, 4
Drama, 1
Drama, 2
Drama, 3
Drama, 4
Drama, 5
Sport, 1
Sport, 2
Sport, 3
```

In case it's relevant, the number of times a genre appears varies. There are also some several hundred .csv files that I need to apply this to, so manually adding this data isn't an option!

I'm wondering if anyone could suggest how I might go about doing this? I'm not the most data literate person, so simple approaches are appreciated! I've learnt a bit about R and suspect that you could do this by writing a script involving an if / else loop (e.g. if next field contains same as previous field add 1 else start from 1 - excuse the poor syntax, but you get the idea!) I'm visualising this data in Tableau and noticed that they now have Tableau Prep - maybe it can be done in there? Any solutions welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this in R. Here's one using functions from the `tidyverse` suite of packages. We first group by genre and then add a column that just counts from 1 to the number of scripts in the genre. I've provided two options for how the new column will look, depending on your needs.

```
library(tidyverse)

# Fake data
set.seed(2)
dat = data.frame(genre = sample(c("Drama", "Comedy", "Sport", "Documentary"), 20, replace=TRUE))

# Add columns to number scripts within each genre
dat = dat %>% 
  group_by(genre) %>% 
  mutate(count = 1:n(),
         count2 = paste0(genre, ", ", 1:n()))

dat
```

> ```
>    genre       count count2                
>  1 Drama           1 Drama, 1      
>  2 Sport           1 Sport, 1      
>  3 Sport           2 Sport, 2      
>  4 Drama           2 Drama, 2      
>  5 Documentary     1 Documentary, 1
>  6 Documentary     2 Documentary, 2
>  7 Drama           3 Drama, 3      
>  8 Documentary     3 Documentary, 3
>  9 Comedy          1 Comedy, 1     
> 10 Sport           3 Sport, 3      
> 11 Sport           4 Sport, 4      
> 12 Drama           4 Drama, 4      
> 13 Documentary     4 Documentary, 4
> 14 Drama           5 Drama, 5      
> 15 Comedy          2 Comedy, 2     
> 16 Documentary     5 Documentary, 5
> 17 Documentary     6 Documentary, 6
> 18 Drama           6 Drama, 6      
> 19 Comedy          3 Comedy, 3     
> 20 Drama           7 Drama, 7
> ```

If you'd like the data sorted, you can do, for example:

```
dat %>% arrange(genre, count)
```

> ```
>    genre       count count2             
>  1 Comedy          1 Comedy, 1     
>  2 Comedy          2 Comedy, 2     
>  3 Comedy          3 Comedy, 3     
>  4 Documentary     1 Documentary, 1
>  5 Documentary     2 Documentary, 2
>  6 Documentary     3 Documentary, 3
>  7 Documentary     4 Documentary, 4
>  8 Documentary     5 Documentary, 5
>  9 Documentary     6 Documentary, 6
> 10 Drama           1 Drama, 1      
> 11 Drama           2 Drama, 2      
> 12 Drama           3 Drama, 3      
> 13 Drama           4 Drama, 4      
> 14 Drama           5 Drama, 5      
> 15 Drama           6 Drama, 6      
> 16 Drama           7 Drama, 7      
> 17 Sport           1 Sport, 1      
> 18 Sport           2 Sport, 2      
> 19 Sport           3 Sport, 3      
> 20 Sport           4 Sport, 4
> ```

Comment: Brilliant, this looks like it'll do the job! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- data.frame(genre = c("Documentary", "Documentary", "Documentary", "Sport", "Sport", "Drama"), rating = c(2,2,4,4,6,6))
df %>% group_by(genre) %>% mutate(id = row_number()) %>% unite(genre_number, c("genre", "id"), sep = " ")

    # A tibble: 6 x 2
  genre_number  rating
  <chr>          <dbl>
1 Documentary 1      2
2 Documentary 2      2
3 Documentary 3      4
4 Sport 1            4
5 Sport 2            6
6 Drama 1            6
```

Edit: to deal with your batch file processing, you can make anything a function and apply it over a list of files.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

number_genres <- function(x) {
x %>% 
  group_by(genre) %>%
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
  unite(genre_number, c("genre", "id"), sep = " ")
}

dir <- "C:/Documents/test" #location of your .csv files
filenames <- list.files(path = dir, pattern = "*.csv", full.names = FALSE) # gets your file names
data_list <- lapply(filenames, read.csv) # reads your files
names(data_list) <- filenames #names your list with respective csv names
numbered <- lapply(data_list, number_genres) # apply your function to your data_list

lapply(1:length(numbered), function(i) write.csv(numbered[[i]], 
                                                file = paste0(names(numbered[i])),
                                                row.names = FALSE)) #writes the data to .csv
```